# Rails testing a model says 'Expected false to be truthy'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I am having site where users can create products upon signup and products can have checklists.

I am having a checklist table with following columns:-

```
id  |  product_id  | content  |  archived
```

I am new to rails testing. I wrote the test below

```
  test 'should have content' do
    checklist = Checklist.new
    assert checklist.save
  end
```

and run the test with following command

```
ruby -I test test/models/checklist_test.rb
```

and test is failed with **Expected false to be truthy**  error.

Is it because of the problem a checklist can be accessed using user.product.checklists i have to populate the data in fixtures first and call those in testing?

**EDIT 1**

I don't have any validations in checklist model.

`class Checklist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end`

I added **!** in test **save** like below

```
  test 'should have content' do
    checklist = Checklist.new
    assert checklist.save!
  end
```

and got this error

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Product must exist

cause the table has product_id in it. I don't know how to supply data to rails test. Any help?

**EDIT 2**

The error is eliminated after editing like below.

`class Checklist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
end`

However i want to test the model with `product` present. I don't know how to supply data to the test with fixtures as if there is no foreign key i can use `Checklist.new` in test.

Since it has foreign key how can i supply data to `Checklist` as it belongs to `Product` which itself belongs to `User`?

Comment: Does `Checklist` have validations? (Including those that might result from association declarations, say, as in rails 5.)

Comment: @jvillian There is no validation. Updated the question above.

Comment: @max Yeah. You are right. After entering `optional:true` there is no error.

Comment: Just so you're clear, your `Checklist` *does* have a validation. It is, as indicated below, a built-in validation from your `belongs_to` declaration which is why I included the parenthetical in my original comment.

Answer (score 5):

`checklist.save` will return `false` if the `checklist` failed to save for some reason; presumably because a **validation failed**.

For example, perhaps your `app/models/checklists.rb` contains something like:

```
validates :product_id, presence: true
```

Or:

```
validates :content, length: { minimum: 10 }
```

Etc. In this simple scenario, you can probably easily determine the error by just looking at the model definition; but for a more complex application you could view: `checklist.errors.messages` to see a list of reasons why the record failed to save.

Judging by the test name (**"should have content"**), my guess is that it's failing because `content` cannot be blank!

To make this test pass, for example, perhaps you need to write:

```
test 'should have content' do
  checklist = Checklist.new(content: 'hello world')
  assert checklist.save
end
```

---

One common approach that people use when testing this sort of thing is to define a "valid record" in [factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails); this lets you explicitly test for *invalid* records, rather than having to explicitly re-define valid records in lots of place. For example, here you could do:

```
# test/factories/checklists.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :checklist do
    content 'test content'
  end
end

# test/models/checklist_test.rb
test 'should have content' do
  checklist = build(:checklist, content: nil)
  refute checklist.save # Expecting this to FAIL!
  assert_includes "Content cannot be nil", checklist.errors
end
```

(Code may not be 100% complete/accurate; but you get the idea)

Comment: Always test with `record.save!`, with the exclamation point `!`, if you want the record to be saved, so if it fails it raises an exception that stops the test, and explains exactly what went wrong.

Comment: @tom Lord My model checklist.rb doesn't have any validations set.

Comment: `class Checklist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end`

Comment: @PraveenKJ In Rails 5, `belongs_to` adds a validation for presence of the product. If you want to turn this off and make it optional, you can specify `optional: true` as an option. Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional

Comment: @Phlip Whilst I agree with you in general, I think it's perfectly valid to test for **a specific validation error message** in a test like this, rather than simply "the record failed to save". That way, if you have an error in your factory (or whatever) then only a minimal number of tests fail.

Comment: @PraveenKJ As I explained above, you could have seen the error message for yourself by inspecting: `checklist.errors.messages`.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned Fixtures to solve this problem.

Fixtures are designed in a way that even associated data(association in model) can be done. For example in my test i have written

```
checklist = checklists(:one)
```

to get a test data for checklist. In checklists fixtures(checklists.yml)

```
  one:
    product: one
    content: Entry
    hashtag: '#markets'
    archived: false
    done: false
```

where

```
product: one
```

refers to **:one** data in **products.yml** which is

```
  one:
   user: one
   name: Test
   role: Will decide
```

and thus association in fixtures is done.